# JavaScript, приватные переменные

Tags: javascript

Как можно создать в классе (ecma6 class) приватную переменную?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В es6 такой возможности нет. Многие думают, что классы `es6` это какая-то новая конструкция или реализация , нет. Это обычный , новый синтаксис для старого доброго прототипного наследования.

```
class Animal {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "dog"
    }
    say()  { alert("gaf") }
}
```

То же самое, что и

```
 function Animal() {
     this.name = "dog"
 }
 Animal.prototype.say = function () { alert("gaf") }
```

Поэтому приватных методов в классе не реализовано, вам придется решать эту проблему самому. Как? Например, через замыкание

```
 const Animal = function () {
     let privateProp = "i am private";

     class Animal {
         constructor() {
             this.name = "dog";
         }
         // гетеры и сеттеры для свойства
         get PrivateProp() { return privateProp }
         set PrivateProp(value) { privateProp = value } 
     }

     return new Animal();
 };

 let dog = new Animal();
 dog.privateProp; // приватное свойство
 dog.privateProp = "new private prop"; // меняем приватное свойство
```

Тут методы `get/set` просто для примера, в реальности скорее всего их не будет, если уже переменная приватная. Тут `get/set` единственные способы достучатся до `privateProp`, больше никак, уберете `get/set` `privateProp` станет настоящим приватным способом.

**UPD**
Чуть ошибся, переменная создавалась бы одна для всех экземпляров, как написали в комментарии, поправил ответ.
Теперь всегда будет создаваться свой экземпляр приватной переменной

Comment: Ну нельзя же так делать! У вас теперь `privateProp` не только приватная, но и статическая...

Comment: @PavelMayorov можно поподробнее, почему так нельзя делать?

Comment: @Юрий, в первом варианте создавалась одна переменная для всех экземпляров. Поэтому если мы где то поменяли бы ее, то она поменялась бы для всех экземпляров класса.

Comment: @ThisMan, понятно,спасибо! Я не успел увидеть, там var privateProp было?

Comment: @Юрий, нет, в первом варианте Animal сам был ф-цие конструктором, сейчас же эта функция, которая вызывает ф-цию конструктор) Поэтому при каждом вызове создается новое замыкание с переменной `privateProp`

Comment: @ThisMan теперь разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: @ThisMan а как можно в такой реализации проверить, что (dog instanceof Animal)? Просто так почему-то не работает

Comment: @Юрий В такой реализации - нельзя. Потому что тут `Animal` - не конструктор, а обычная функция.

Comment: ThisMan, теперь у вас создается по новому классу на каждый вызов "конструктора". Зачем в такой схеме вообще нужны классы?

Comment: @PavelMayorov чтобы сделать приватные поля

Comment: @Юрий я вас не понимаю. Вы сейчас кому ответили?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не увидел, подумал, Вы меня спросили

Comment: Что за бред? Даже переменные созданные в конструкторе вины лишь в области его видимости, и не видны остальным методам, надо свойства класса хранить в `this` и только в `this`, давая лишь уникальные имена, для этого и придумали `Symbol`  ну или `Math.random()` как полифилл

Comment: Раскладываем запас костылей на будущее? Даже если забить на производительность, то за что какому-то бедному программисту должно достаться `dog instanceof Animal` = false?

Answer (score 6):

Для приватных свойств надо использовать замыкания и символы.

```
 const Animal = (function () {
     const privatePropSymbol = Symbol("privateProp");

     class Animal {
         // гетеры и сеттеры для свойства
         get PrivateProp() { return this[privatePropSymbol]; }
         set PrivateProp(value) { this[privatePropSymbol] = value } 
     }

     Animal.prototype[privatePropSymbol] = "default value";
     return Animal;
 })();
```

Фокус в том, что два символа с одинаковым названием остаются двумя разными символами - поэтому не имея переменной `privatePropSymbol` внешний код не сможет получить к нему доступ.

Comment: вы наверное не знаете что в ES6 можно писать выражения в именах полей  в квадратных скобках? `class Cat { [1+2](){ функция с именем '3'  } }`

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus, причем тут это, если в данном случае имя известно заранее?

Comment: @Grundy при чем тут известно зарание если мы про Symbol говорим, как он может быть известен зарание? Вначале создал класс, а потом ему вручную прототип расширяет.

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus, так в каком месте примера из данного ответа нужно использовать вычисляемое имя метода?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а так можно?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, тем что он предлагает **метод** сделать `[1+2]()` с  полями как я понял пока такое не работает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42653/discussion-between-grundy-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 2):

Теперь это делается намного проще с помощью синтаксиса `#`:

```js
class WithPrivateFields {
  #privateField = 'Private Field';
  static #staticPrivateField = 'Static Private Field';
  
  get privateField() {
    return this.#privateField;
  }
  
  static get staticPrivateField() {
    return this.#staticPrivateField;
  }
}

const obj = new WithPrivateFields();

console.log(obj.privateField);
console.log(obj['privateField']);
console.log(obj['#privateField']);

console.log(WithPrivateFields.staticPrivateField);
console.log(WithPrivateFields['staticPrivateField']);
console.log(WithPrivateFields['#staticPrivateField']);
```

Answer (score 0):

А ВОТ ТАК (при чем так можно делать уже 200 лет отроду):

ES6:

```
var say = Symbol()

class Cat {

   constructor(){
      this[say]() // call private
   }

   [say](){
      alert('im private')
   }

}
```

ES5:

```
var say = Math.random() // pollyfill Symbol()

function Cat(){
  this[say]() // call private methods
}

Cat.prototype[say] = function(){ alert('im a private') }
```

Пример использования ES6:

```
var handlers = Symbol()

class EventEmitter {

  constructor(){
    this[handlers] = [] 
  }

  on(handler){
    this[handlers].push(handler) 
  }

  emit(){
    for(let handler of this[handlers]) handler()
  }

}


class Cat extends EventEmitter {

}


var q = new Cat()
q.on // function
q.emit // function
q.handlers // undefined cuz PRIVATE ;)
```

И не обязательно больше учить названия свойств из реализации класса, таких как внутреннее свойство handlers, боясь их случайно перекрыть в классах наследниках. Использую приватные уже 6 лет. И ни каких проблем с утечками. Не понимаю людей которые говорят что в яваскрипте приватных нет.

Наслаждайтесь, и поменьше слушайте всяких неумех ;)

Comment: пример с ES5 - не аналог примера с Symbol

Comment: А какие проблемы с утечками ожидались?

Comment: В JavaScript **приватных свойств нет**, так уж устроен язык. Все, что вы привели, это обходные пути, позволяющие _эмулировать_ приватные свойства. Это не одно и тоже. Ну и ваш вариант ES5 будет приводить к неожиданным для новичков эффектам при использовании `for in` или `for of`. От меня минус.

Comment: "Ни единого разрыва." Слишком много бравады. Как насчёт `q[handlers]`?

Comment: Однако, справедливости ради, хочу заметить, что символы - хорошая **эмуляция** приватных свойств. Только вот нежелательно сорить ими в глобальном scope

Comment: И по поводу приватности: даже в [таком](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622463/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-javascript/622516#622516) варианте, можно получить все ключи с помощью [Object.getOwnPropertySymbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols)

Comment: @vp_arth Тогда это уже будет осознанно, а мы хотим защитить от случайного пересечения имен. Ну либо можно создать новый приметив типа  privates