# Инкапсуляция JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как достать инкапсулированное значение в прототип?

Как это выглядит:

```
function A(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    var arr = [a,b];
}
A.prototype.A1 = function(){
    console.log(this.a);
}
A.prototype.A2 = function(){
    console.log(this.arr);
}

var a1 = new A(1,2);
a1.A1();//1
a1.A2();//undefined
```

Как использовать `arr` в прототипе?

Comment: никак. Это невозможно

Comment: о каких call/apply идет речь, если ответ на вопрос: как достать локально объявленную переменную? ответ один - никак.

Answer (score 15):

`arr` в данном коде является *локальной* переменной.

Доступ к локальной переменной может быть осуществлен только внутри функции, в которой объявлена переменная.

Либо во внутренних функциях.

```
function A(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    var arr = [a,b];

    function B(){
        console.log('B', arr); // доступно
    }

    console.log('A', arr); // доступно
}

A.prototype.C = function (){ /* arr недоступен */ }
```

Таким образом, использовать локальную переменную `arr` где-то еще кроме функции `A` - невозможно.

Answer (score 11):

Рекомендую использовать `Symbol` для реализации более-менее приватных членов "класса".

```js
var A = (function() {
  var arrKey = Symbol();

  A.prototype.getArr = function() {
    return this[arrKey];
  };

  return A;

  function A(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this[arrKey] = [a, b];
  };
})();


var a1 = new A(1, 2);
console.log(a1.getArr()); // [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 7):

Ну если очень хочется, а условная приватность символов не устраивает, то можно так (при наличии `WeakMap` из ES6):

```js
var Smth = (function () {
  var privates = new WeakMap;

  function Smth(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    privates.set(this, {y: y});
  }
  
  Smth.prototype.doSmth = function () {
    console.log(this.x + ' ' + privates.get(this).y);
  };
  
  return Smth;
})();

var a = new Smth(10, 13);
var b = new Smth(123, 167);

a.doSmth();
b.doSmth();
```

Answer (score 5):

Как один из вариантов, так:

```js
function A(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    var arr = [a,b];

    A.prototype.getArr = function () {
        return arr;
    }
}
A.prototype.A1 = function(){
    console.log(this.a);
};
A.prototype.A2 = function(){
    console.log(A.prototype.getArr());
};

var a1 = new A(1,2);
a1.A1();//1
a1.A2();//[1, 2]
```

Дополнено:

Если с несколькими экземплярами, тогда можно так попробовать:

```js
function A(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    var arr = [a, b];
    this.xxx = arr;
}

A.prototype.A1 = function(){
    console.log(this.a);
};
A.prototype.A2 = function(){
    console.log(this.xxx);
};

var a1 = new A(1,2);
var a2 = new A(2,3);
var a3 = new A(3,4);
a1.A1();//1
a1.A2();//[1, 2]
a2.A2();//[2, 3]
a3.A2();//[3, 4]
```

Вообще, если предположить, что функцию  `A`  менять нельзя, то, видимо, никак не получить значение `arr`.

Comment: попробуй создать несколько объектов и посмотреть что выведет A2

Comment: Тогда уж `this.getArr = function(){return arr.slice();}`

Comment: `.slice()` в данном конкретном случае не дает эффекта.

Comment: `.slice` возвращает копию, реализуя read-only доступ. Если нужен rw доступ - нет причин не написать `this.arr=[this.a, this.b]`

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать "геттер" и достать значение так:

```js
function A(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    var arr = [a,b];
    this.getArray = function () {
        return arr;
    }
}
A.prototype.A1 = function(){
    console.log(this.a);
}
A.prototype.A2 = function(){
    console.log(this.getArray());
}

var a1 = new A(1,2);
a1.A1();
a1.A2();
```

Comment: А где у вас тут геттер?

Comment: @vp_arth Это я образно выражаясь. Он так же абстрактен, как и приватные свойства через underscore

Answer (score 2):

Все переменные, объявленные внутри функции, являются приватными для неё. Доступ к ним может быть осуществлён только из самой функции и через замыкание из вложенных в неё.

Поскольку в нормальной реализации класса фукнции помещаются в прототип и существуют в единственном экземпляре, они не могут через замыкание получить доступ к инстансным переменным (функция одна, а инстансов много - функция не может "выбирать" замыкание в момент вызова).

Возможны следующие решения:

## Классическое соглашение о подчёркивании в имени

Если имя начинается с подчёркивания, то по устному соглашению считается, что его не надо трогать. Естественно, на уровне кода это никакой приватности не обеспечивает.

## Отказаться от методов в прототипе и помещать методы в экземпляры

Приватность таким образом обеспечивается, однако происходит создание большого числа однотипных функций, отличающихся только замыканиями.

Этот подход считается нерациональным, однако довольно распространён в реализации различных сервисов, которые по сути являются синглтонами.

## [Использовать Symbol в качестве ключа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/622516/178988)

Тип `Symbol` является особым типом ключа. Получить доступ к значению поля можно только имея сам символ, через который это значение было записано.

Это достаточно похоже на приватность, однако не даёт полную защиту от доступа, поскольку все символы-ключи для объекта можно получить через `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`.

`Symbol` - это ES6. Полифилы для него генерируют обычное поле с достаточно рандомным ключом, чтобы исклчить пересечения с другими полями.

## [Использовать некий словарь в замыкании](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/630505/178988)

Одно замыкание может быть общим для конструктора и всех прототипных методов. Но инстансы надо как-то различать. Если поместить в это замыкание нечто, где инстанс является ключом, а значением является весь набор приватных полей, то мы получим полную настоящую приватность.

Однако, тут есть проблема. Если мы будем держать что-то типа массива, то оно будет удерживать все наши объекты от сборки мусора, т. е. получается утечка памяти. Эту проблему решает введённый в ES6 `WeakMap`, который позволяет сборщику мусора уничтожать объекты, являющиеся его ключами.

Полифилом для `WeakMap` является помещение некого поля в сам объект и сохранение имени этого поля в карте. По сути, скатываемся к предыдущему способу.

Answer (score 2):

> Вот написал я это всё и понял, что приватность-то всё ещё не совсем настоящая. Можно подменить функцию `private` (можно было бы решить через readonly в defineProperty, но всё равно можно Object.create поверх и защита не сработает) и получить таким образом ключ, который ей дают, а дальше уже по этому ключу извлечь данные.

<s>Всё-таки придумал способ получить полноценную приватность в ES5:</s>

Но всё равно интересно. Может быть кто-то додумает эту идею до конца.

```js
var Smth = (function () {
  var PKEY = {}; // Объект-ключ для доступа к приватным данным, который
                 // доступен только в замыкании, т. к. нигде не отдаётся наружу

  function Smth(x, y) {
    this.x = x;

    var privates = {y:y}; // Объект с приватными значениями, который
                          // отдаётся только через функцию this.private
                          // ... которая его не отдаст, если ей не дадут ключ
    var me = this;
    
    this.private = function (pkey) {
      if (this && this !== window && this !== me) { 
        throw new Error("Do not call `private` on foreign object");
      }
    
      if (pkey === PKEY) {
        return privates; // PKEY снаружи не знают, значит обращение идёт изнутри
      }

      throw new Error("Access to privates is denied");
    }
  }
  
  Smth.prototype.doSmth = function () {
    var privates = this.private(PKEY);
    console.log(this.x + ' ' + privates.y);
  };
  
  return Smth;
})();

var a = new Smth(10, 13);
var b = new Smth(123, 167);

a.doSmth();
b.doSmth();
```

Но этот способ ещё нужно адаптировать для наследования, поскольку каждый наследник затирает родительскую реализацию `this.private`, получается, что родительский класс не теряет свой приватный объект. Чтобы этого не происходило, надо немного изменить реализацию метода, чтобы он прокидывал вызов к родительскому методу (ведь там тоже будет проверка собственного ключа). А исключение оставим последнему уровню, когда родительского метода уже нет.

В следующем коде в `Smth` заменена только функция

```js
var Smth = (function () {
  var PKEY = {}; // Объект-ключ для доступа к приватным данным, который
                 // доступен только в замыкании, т. к. нигде не отдаётся наружу

  function Smth(x, y) {
  var basePrivate = this.private; // Тут получится undefined

    this.x = x;

    var privates = {y:y}; // Объект с приватными значениями, который
                          // отдаётся только через функцию this.private
                          // ... которая его не отдаст, если ей не дадут ключ
    var me = this;
    
    this.private = function (pkey) {
      if (this && this !== window && this !== me) {
        throw new Error("Do not call `private` to foreign object");
      }
    
      if (pkey === PKEY) {
        return privates; // PKEY снаружи не знают, значит обращение идёт изнутри
      }

      if (basePrivate) {
        return basePrivate(pkey);
      }

      throw new Error("Access to privates is denied");
    }
  }
  
  Smth.prototype.doSmth = function () {
    var privates = this.private(PKEY);
    console.log(this.x + ' ' + privates.y);
  };
  
  return Smth;
})();

var Derived = (function () {
  var PKEY = {}; // Объект-ключ для доступа к приватным данным, который
                 // доступен только в замыкании, т. к. нигде не отдаётся наружу

  function Derived(x, y, a, b) {
    Smth.call(this, x, y);
  
  var basePrivate = this.private; // Это функция - она не вызывается тут

    this.a = a;

    var privates = {b:b}; // Объект с приватными значениями, который
                          // отдаётся только через функцию this.private
                          // ... которая его не отдаст, если ей не дадут ключ
    var me = this;
    
    this.private = function (pkey) {
      if (this && this !== window && this !== me) {
        throw new Error("Do not call `private` to foreign object");
      }
    
      if (pkey === PKEY) {
        return privates; // PKEY снаружи не знают, значит обращение идёт изнутри
      }

      if (basePrivate) {
        return basePrivate(pkey);
      }

      throw new Error("Access to privates is denied");
    }
  }
  
  Derived.prototype = Object.create(Smth.prototype);

  Derived.prototype.doOtherThing = function () {
    var privates = this.private(PKEY);
    console.log(this.x + ' ' + this.a + ' ' + privates.b);
  };
  
  return Derived;
})();

var a = new Derived(10, 13, -8, -67);
var b = new Derived(123, 167, -411, -77);

a.doSmth();
a.doOtherThing();
b.doSmth();
b.doOtherThing();
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr` объявляется только в `function A`. Чтобы "внедрить" `arr` в прототип, вам надо написать:

```
function A(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.arr = [a,b];
}
```

Comment: А где инкапсуляция?

Comment: Вы иначе не "внедрите" arr в прототип