# В чем принципиальная разница между call/apply и почему код так работает?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Разрешите задать нубский вопрос по CALL/APPLY, может кто-то разжуёт
Как следует из многих туториалов и учебников call отличается от apply тем, что в apply аргументом можно передать массив. А в call нет.

```
var object = {
    "arr": ["Первый элемент",2,3,4,5],
    "func": function() {
        function awayFromMe(arr){
            console.log(arr);
        }
    awayFromMe.call (this, this.arr);
    awayFromMe.apply(this, this.arr);
    }
};
object.func();
```

То-есть я рассчитывал что call ничего не даст, a apply отработает, но вопреки моим ожиданиям
call дал вывод массива:["Первый элемент", 2, 3, 4, 5]
apply дал вывод только первого элемента: "Первый элемент"

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Путём проб и ошибок, мне кажется я уловил тонкий смысл различия между call/apply и хотел бы им с Вами поделиться, может ещё будет такой(-ая) же как я. Итак, допустим, у нас есть простая заданная функция, которая возвращает сумму двух чисел:

```
function sumTwoNumb(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Код крайне простой, мы передаём два аргумента в параметры функции, а она возвращает сумму. И допустим, нам надо вызвать эту функцию для двух элементов некоего массива.

---

Если мы вызовем её как: `sumTwoNumb.call(null, [100,150])`, то получится так, что первый параметр `a` получит аргументом весь массив `[100,150]`, а второй параметр, `b` не получит ничего и станет, соответственно, undefined. И в итоге функция вернёт результат сложения `[100,150]+undefined`, а это равно `100,150undefined`.

---

А если мы её вызовем так: `sumTwoNumb.apply(null, [100,150])`, то при входе в функцию первый параметр `a` получит нулевой элемент массива `= 100`, а второй параметр получит первый элемент массива `= 150` и в итоге функция вернёт результат сложения `100 + 150`, то есть верный.

Уважаемые профессионалы, если я не прав, поправьте. Надеюсь, кому-то пригодится.

Comment: Твой ответ ничем не отличается от уже присутствующих. И к нему вполне подходит твой же комментарий: _А что это даёт? **Ну допустим я опущу аргументы в функции, а вытащу их через arguments**. Если call - то там будет объект с массивом, а если apply то просто массив ..._

Comment: @Grundy, если его формулировка ему самому понятнее, то не исключено, что она же будет понятнее для других новичков. Я(и, судя по голосам, сообщество) считаю - пусть будет

Comment: @Anon, у меня претензия не к формулировке, а к тому, что он сам не ответил на свой же комментарий. Таким образом непонятно, что именно нового добавил его ответ к существующим, а также, как именно он отвечает на его же вопросы, которые он задавал в комментариях.

Comment: @Anon, может и так, но задать вопрос, почитать ответы, скопировать их в свой "ответ" практически полностью - это нехорошо. Впрочем, понял -- и то ладно.

Comment: @Other, в том и дело, что читая  ваши ответы сейчас, когда я понимаю в чем разница, я вижу что многие тут писали верные вещи, но мне нужен был элементарный пример, который показал бы как именно распределяются элементы массива по аргументам в call и в apply. Ваш ответ был абсолютно верным, но слишком расплывчатым. Сейчас я вижу кристалл Вашей мысли и мне понятно что Вы имели ввиду, но тогда не смог понять. Как я и говорю, мне требовался самый элементарный пример, чтобы я мог понять механику распределения этих элементов по параметрам.

Comment: @ДенисИванов, а что по поводу ответа vp_arth, в котором был пример с вызовом, который даже можно было запустить и увидеть разницу? И ты так и не ответил на свой же вопрос, про доставание из arguments.

Comment: Про arguments: если у нас уже есть функция, в которой нельзя изменить код, можно только ей что-то передать и она что-то вернёт. То-есть можно через arguments - но когда есть доступ к телу функции и её несложно переписать. А по поводу ответа, который написал vp_arth ... сейчас я её вижу, но тогда не понимал. Есть отличная фраза: отладка сложнее написания кода, и если вы пишите код настолько заумно насколько сможете - то априори не сможете его отлаживать. Этой сентенцией я имею ввиду то, что мне для понимания не хватало именно элементарнейшего примера, чтобы понять механизм. В общем как-то так.

Answer (score 5):

[foo.apply(thisArg, argsArray)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
[foo.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> хотя синтаксис функции call() практически полностью идентичен функции
>   apply(), фундаментальное различие между ними заключается в том, что
>   функция call() принимает список аргументов, в то время, как функция
>   apply() - одиночный массив аргументов.

Т.е. разница только в том, что в `apply` вы передаёте аргументы в виде массива, а в `call` как есть:

```js
function test(a, b, c, d) {
  console.log(a, b, c, d);
}
// Последующие вызовы идентичны
test.apply(null, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
test.call(null, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Другой пример:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];

// Один аргумент - массив
console.log.call(console, a); // [1, 2, 3]

// Три аргумента
console.log.apply(console, a); // 1, 2, 3

// функция суммирует свои аргументы
const sum = (...args) => args.reduce((c, a)=> c += a, 0);

console.info('call', sum.call(null, a)); // sum([1,2,3]) = 0+'1,2,3'
console.info('apply', sum.apply(null, a)); // sum(1,2,3) = 6
```

Comment: А что это даёт то? Какая разница как передавать? Я же могу массив и в call передать, а в функции вытащить его через arguments

Comment: `call` вы используете, когда у вас есть все аргументы по отдельности. Когда есть массив неизвестной длины, у вас это не выйдет. Для этого есть `apply`

Comment: В новых спецификациях `ecmascript` можно развернуть массив в раздельные аргументы: `foo.call(null, ...arr1, ...arr2)`. Функция будет вызвана со всеми элементами обоих массивов.

Comment: Что значит массив неизвестной длины? Массив формирующийся динамически, например при использовании Array.fiter? `var object = {
    "arr": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    "func": function() {
        function awayFromMe(){
            console.log(arguments); //[Array[6]]
        }

        awayFromMe.call(this, this.arr.filter(function(elem){if(elem>=5)return elem}));
    }
};
object.func();
` И ведь все равно работает ...

Comment: Что значит работает? Вы передали один аргумент - массив. А функция может хотеть несколько, по раздельности

Comment: А можно небольшой пример, пожалуйста. А то я могу call'ом хоть 100 массивов передать сотней аргументов. Вытащить через arguments

Comment: Добавил другой пример

Comment: @ДенисИванов, вытащить через arguments ты можешь только если это твоя функция. и то, нужно будет проверять пришел ли массив потому что вызвали через call, или это просто в качестве первого аргумента передали массив. Если же функция не твоя, то call с массивом может быть не применим. Просто пример функция [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) принимает список объектов, а не массив. Поэтому если ты не знаешь сколько у тебя будет deferred объектов, единственный способ вызвать ее и получить корректный результат - использовать _apply_. Хотя вру, еще есть вариант с bind.

Comment: @Grundy, это же **тот самый** ДенисИванов, который [что-то](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622463/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-javascript) знает про call/apply.

Comment: @vp_arth, я думаю здесь просто путаница с вопросами при назначении конкурса, и конкурс должен был быть на этот вопрос

Comment: Странно, назначал именно сюда. А переместилось туда ...

Comment: Этот вопрос был задан 2ч назад. О каком конкурсе речь?

Comment: @Grundy, не совсем понял. Я не работаю с JQuery, поэтому понять что такое $.when не могу

Comment: @ДенисИванов, именно поэтому в комментарии есть ссылка на документацию для этого метода:)

Comment: @ДенисИванов привет, я модератор. Вы случайно назначили конкурс на другом вопросе и хотите его отменить?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, было бы неплохо. Сюда назначать не надо, ибо я сам ответил на свой вопрос путём проб и ошибок. Дополнил свой пост. Как то так

Comment: @ДенисИванов, это ваше дополнение желательно оформить  и перенести в ответ.

Comment: @ vp_arth, я так делал до этого, но его удалили, сказали что нельзя отвечать на свой вопрос=)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @ДенисИванов сейчас уже поздно отменять, хотя бы потому, что после объявления конкурса появились новые ответы. Будет нечестно по отношению к их авторам. В целом отменять конкурс можно только в порядке исключения и сразу — например, когда случайно не туда нажали.

Comment: @ДенисИванов, не могли сказать, что _нельзя отвечать на свой вопрос_, могли сказать _в данном сообщении **не содержится ответа** на вопрос_.

Answer (score 1):

Всё верно, `call` в первом аргументе возвращает массив, а `apply` распределяет элементы массива по аргументам, т. е. `arr` будет указывать на первый элемент `Первый элемент`.

Comment: А что это даёт? Ну допустим я опущу аргументы в функции, а вытащу их через arguments. Если call - то там будет объект с массивом, а если apply то просто массив ...

Comment: Только не возвращает, а принимает.