# Javascript this в классах

Tags: javascript

Допустим, существует класс:

```
function MyClass {
   self = this; // Создаст глобальный объект self
   $(document).ready(this.g);
}

MyClass.prototype.g = function(event) { 
   // здесь this - это объект вызывавший событие.
   // обращаемся к полям класса через self
}
```

Но `self` - это глобальный объект, если мы таким же образом определим другой класс, с таким же `self`, то он собъет `self` текущего.

Я вижу решение только в выдаче каждому объекту своего id и обращению к ним через глобальный массив в функциях подобным `g`.

Существуют другие способы обойти это?

Comment: Глобальный `self` создать нельзя потому что он уже занят.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631589/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy да, вы правы, оказывается это поле объекта window, но я его сбивал, следуя практике используемой другими. Дело совсем не в этом.

Comment: Ответ обновлён.

Comment: можно попробовать использовать let self

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready((e) => this.g(e));
```

или

```
this.bound_g = this.g.bind(this);
$(document).ready(this.bound_g);
```

тогда

```
MyClass.prototype.g = function(event) { 
   // здесь this - это объект MyClass 
}
```

Другой вариант:

```
var self = this;
$(document).ready(function(event) { 
  self.g(this, event);
});

MyClass.prototype.g = function(element, event) { 
   // здесь this - это объект MyClass 
}
```

Comment: В моём классе используются как `unbind`, так и `removeEventListener`, так не получится, к сожалению.

Comment: @OlegUP я не понимаю, что Вы хотите сказать

Comment: нельзя использовать анонимные функции, если поведением в коде заложено удаление обработчиков событий. https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener-i-removeeventlistener

Comment: @OlegUP хм, ну сохраните результат `this.g.bind(this)` в свойство объекта, прежде чем назначать обработчик события

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $(document).ready(this.g);
> ```

```
$(document).ready(this.g.bind(this));
```

> В моём классе используются как unbind, так и removeEventListener, так не получится, к сожалению.

```
constructor() {
  this.g = this.g.bind(this);
}

doSmth() {
  $(document).ready(this.g);
}
```

Comment: выполняя присваивание в `this.g` потеряется преимущества класса на прототипах?

Comment: @OlegUP, если ты о моём варианте (а не о присваивании лямбды в конструкторе вместо прототипного метода) возможность перекрывать методы в наследниках и экономия памяти на функциях сохранятся, а возможность динамически изменять и создавать методы для уже созданных объектов потеряется.

Comment: этого достаточно, спасибо, не помешал бы конечно, ещё, источник где говорится о структуре класса при такой практике. Я проверю это сейчас, и в случае успеха отмечу ваш ответ как верный.

Comment: http://bit.ly/2SarUwc
Здесь я присваиваю результат bind в `__proto__`, только тогда эта функция будет одна для всех объектов.
присваивание же в this без `__proto__` будет создавать отдельную функцию в каждом экземпляре.

Comment: @OlegUP, где ты в моём коде нашёл `__proto__`? Функция в прототипе. В каждый экземпляр попадает своя функция, которую вернёт `bind`.