# Тип данных Symbol JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

В JS можно создать уникальный идентификатор с помощью `Symbol()`, например

```
children: HTMLCollection(2)
  0: input
  1: div
  length: 2
  __proto__: HTMLCollection
    ...
    constructor: ƒ HTMLCollection()
    Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
    Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "HTMLCollection"
    ...
    __proto__: Object
```

Для чего это может понадобится если можно использовать `Object`?
И как его можно привести например к такому виду?

```
Foo(2)
  0: true
  1: 1
  length: 2
  __proto__: Foo
    ...
    constructor: ƒ Foo()
    Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
    Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Foo"
    ...
    __proto__: Object
```

Comment: что значит _можно создать свой тип данных_? `HTMLCollection` - это интерфейс предоставляемый браузером. И как ко всему этому относится `Symbol`?

Comment: @Grundy `HTMLCollection`  взял просто для наглядности, "свой тип данных" сейчас перефразирую

Comment: Посмотри вопрос дубликат - судя по всему, это именно то что ты и хотел

Comment: @Grundy, да это оно. Прочитал статью  [ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/symbol) и не могу понять, для какой задачи это может применяться?

Comment: Ну, помимо того, что есть, так называемые _известные символы_, свойства с такими именами могут обрабатываться особенно, это можно использовать как замену приватным полям [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516498/186999)

Comment: Оказывается ты же и спрашивал :)